# REST API Optional parameters

Tags: c#, rest

I build a Web Role with rest api. All its arguments should be optional with default values

I tried this:

```
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "RetrieveInformation/param1/{param1}/param2/{param2}/param3/{param3}")]
    public string RetrieveInformation(string param1, string param2, string param3)
    {

    }
```

I want that it will work for the following scenarios:

```
https://127.0.0.1/RetrieveInformation/param1/2  

https://127.0.0.1/RetrieveInformation/param1/2/param3/3
```

How can I do that?Will the below work?

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "RetrieveInformation/param1/{param1=1}/param2/{param2=2}/param3/{param3=3}")]
```

Comment: please add tags to question to prevent mix up...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you can achieve this when using segments (i.e. using /). You could use a wildcard character but it only allows you to do so for the last segment.

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "RetrieveInformation/param1/{param1}/{*param2}")]
```

If you don't really need segments and can use query parameters, the following route will work

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "RetrieveInformation?param1={param1}&param2={param2}&param3={param3}")]
```

Such a route will give you flexibility as parameters do not need to be ordered, nor are required. This will work with the following

```
http://localhost:62386/Service1.svc/GetData?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3
http://localhost:62386/Service1.svc/GetData?param1=1&param3=3&param2=2
http://localhost:62386/Service1.svc/GetData?param1=1&param2=2
http://localhost:62386/Service1.svc/GetData?param1=1&param3=3
```

You can find more information about UriTemplate @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The param1 may not be optional when a param2 is defined, so doing this in a single route might be a bit cumbersome (if even possible). It might be better to split your GET into multiple routes.

Something like the below code might work better for you...

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "RetrieveInformation")]
public string Get1()
{
    return RetrieveInfo(1,2,3);
}

[WebGet(UriTemplate = "RetrieveInformation/param1/{param1}")]
public string GetP1(int param1)
{
    return RetrieveInfo(param1,2,3);
}

[WebGet(UriTemplate = "RetrieveInformation/param1/{param1}/param2/{param2}")]
public string GetP1P2(int param1, int param2)
{
    return RetrieveInfo(param1,param2,3);
}

[WebGet(UriTemplate = "RetrieveInformation/param1/{param1}/param3/{param3}")]
public string GetP1P3(int param1, int param3)
{
    return RetrieveInfo(param1,2,param3);
}

private string RetrieveInfo(int p1, int p2, int p3)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: IF I have 100 parameters - based on what you say I`ll need to define at least 100 permutations

Comment: If you have 100 parameters, then a url string is probably not the best place to input them. The maximum URL length is 2083 (or 2048 for the path part in IE). Plus, URLs aren't encoded for HTTPS which means that anyone sniffing the line will be able to see all your personal info in the URL. Consider a POST with the data in the body would be a better way to send this info.